# Segmentation fault in Zend_Tool

Tags: php, zend-framework, segmentation-fault, zend-tool

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 and I applied [this tutorial](http://www.pangpondblog.com/install-zend-framework-18-ubuntu-zendtool)

But I'm still getting this error:

```
$ zf show version
Segmentation fault
```

What do I miss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably a botched extension check you ini's and make sure they are good and that you meet all the requirements for Zend Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the *latest* release of the Zend Framework. I remember having this issue with an older version, but I can't seem to reproduce it anymore with the latest one (1.9.6 at the time I'm writing this).